# Can't intall Win 7 64Bit. Something about GPT disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, gpt

I've got Asrock Z68 Extreme 3 Gen 3 with 2600k. It got the UEFI bios. I got 4 HDDs and I run them as AHCI setup.

Now, I want to install Win7 64Bit over my Win7 32Bit. I boot up from the DVD, all goes well until the menu where I have to choose the HDD I want to install Win7 64Bit on.

I choose c: like always and it tells me

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected Disk has an MBR
>   partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT
>   disks.

What do I do now? I'm currently in Win7 32bit writing this, and this is how my partitions look like from win7 partition manager: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert from MBR to GPT. [TechNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_TechNet) has an article, *[Change a master boot record disk into a GUID partition table disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738416%28WS.10%29.aspx)*, with all of the details.